# conservative extension of the theory

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

There are two languages $L = \{P\}$ and $L' = \{P, f\}$ with equality. $P$ is binary predicate symbol. $f$ is unary functional symbol.

$\varphi_1 ≡ ∀x P(x, x)$

$\varphi_2 ≡ ∀x∀y((P(x, y) ∧ P(y, x)) → x = y)$

$\varphi_3 ≡ ∀x∀y∀z((P(x, y) ∧ P(y, z)) → P(x, z))$

$\varphi_4 ≡ ∀x∃y(P(x, y) ∧ x \ne y)$

$\varphi_5 ≡ ∀x∀y(P(x, y) ∨ P(y, x))$

$\varphi_6 ≡ ∀x (f(x) \ne x ∧ P(x, f(x)) ∧ ∀y ((P(x,y) ∧ P(y, f(x))) → (y = x ∨ y = f(x))))$

$\varphi_7 ≡ ∀x∀y(f(x) = f(y) → P(x, y))$

$\varphi_8 ≡ ∀x ¬P(f(x), x)$

$\varphi_9 ≡ ∀x∀y((P(f(x),y) → P(x, y)) ∧ (P(x, y) → P(x, f(y))))$

There are theories $T=\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3, \varphi_4\}$, $U=\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2,\varphi_3,\varphi_4,\varphi_5\}$ of language $L$ and theory $T_1=\{\varphi_2, \varphi_3, \varphi_6, \varphi_7\}$, $T_2=\{\varphi_1, \varphi_3, \varphi_6, \varphi_8 \}$, $T_3=\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_6, \varphi_9 \}$, $T_4 = \{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_5, \varphi_6, \varphi_9 \}$ of language $L'$

For each of theories $T_1, T_2, T_3$ I need to find if it is an extension and if it is conservative extension of the theory $T$. Also I need to find and prove if $T_4$ is extension and if it is conservative extension of the theory $U$.

Could somebody suggest me some flow of prove? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Think semantically - what is a model of each of the theories in question? Remember that $X$ is an *extension* of $Y$ iff every model of $X$ is a model of $Y$, and $X$ is a *conservative extension* of $Y$ if (but not only if) every model of $Y$ can be expanded to a model of $X$. [The reason I mention this property of conservative extensions is that it's usually what winds up being proved - you start with a model of $Y$ and expand it to a model of $X$, and then argue by Completeness that this means that $X$ is a conservative extension of $Y$.] So: can you characterize the models of the theories?

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not clear for me

Comment: What are these theories - what do they *mean*? It is challenging to just read 9 axioms, with no English descriptions, and work out what they are supposed to mean. You should improve the post by adding the *source* of the problem, more detailed *descriptions* of the axioms, and what you have already tried.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Where can I read proofs for the following facts that you mentioned in your comment? (a) $X$ is an extension of $Y$ iff every model of $X$ is a model of $Y$. (b) $X$ is a conservative extension of $Y$ if (but not only if) every model of $Y$ can be expanded to a model of $X$.

Comment: (a) is the definition of an extension: if $X$ is a theory containing $Y$, then any model of $X$ is a model of $Y$. For (b), suppose that any model of $Y$ can be extended to a model of $X$; then for every sentence $\varphi$ that $X$ proves in the language of $Y$, $\varphi$ must be true in every model of $Y$, since if $M\models Y\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ then $M$ can't be expanded to a model of $X$. (Note that this doesn't reverse - only one direction, "expandability $\rightarrow$ conservative", holds in general.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I apologize, but I'm quite ignorant in matters of logic. I'm familiar with different definitions. Would you please explain how they compare to the ones you mentioned? Let $L_0, L_1$ be first-order languages. (a) An $L_1$-theory, $K_1$, is an extension of an $L_0$-theory, $K_0$, iff $L_0$'s signature is a subset of $L_1$'s signature and $K_0\subseteq K_1$. (b) The extension $K_1$ is conservative iff whenever $\phi$ is a well-formed $L_0$-formula such that $\vdash_{K_1} \phi$, then $\vdash_{K_0} \phi$.

Comment: @EvanAad I was being slightly sloppy - I was speaking of the *deductive closures* of the theories in question. Read my initial comment again, but this time under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are deductively closed (that is, if $X\vdash\varphi$ then $\varphi\in X$, and similarly for $Y$). Remember that each theory has a unique deductive closure, and the models of the deductive closure are exactly the models of the original theory, so in this context we can conflate the two without issue (which is what I was doing above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer, too long for a comment.

I don't recall the difference between conservative and extensions, so I'll outline how to make the equivalences when they occur.

It's much easier to understand if you replace $P(x,y)$ with symbols $x\leq y$. Then the axioms have an obvious interpretation. Write $x<y$ to mean $x\leq y\land x\neq y$.

(1)-(3) are "partial order" axioms.

(4) says there is no maximal element - there is always something bigger.

(5) says it is a total order.

(6) says $x<f(x)$ and no $y$ satisfies $x<y<f(x)$. This means that $f(x)$ is a single atom bigger than $x$.

(7) says that if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x\leq y$.

(8) say that it is never true that $f(x)\leq x$.

(9) says that if $f(x)\leq y$ then $x\leq y$ and that $x\leq y$ implies $x\leq f(y)$.

$T$ is the theory of partial orders without upper bound.

$U$ is the theory of linear orders without upper bounds.

The other ones are harder to interpret, because we don't have all the partial order axioms in them.

### $T_1$

(2) and (3) together, without (1), models a partial order with a set of distinguished elements. That is, we can define:

$$x\leq y := P(x,y)\lor x=y\\
Q(x):=P(x,x)$$

These two entirely determine the theory (2),(3).

(7) shows that $P(x,x)$ is always true, since $\forall x(f(x)=f(x))$ is true. So (1) is true in $T_1$.

(6) implies (4) - the first part of (6) shows there is a "bigger" element than every $x$.

So, $T_1$ proves all the axioms of $T$, and $Q$ really adds nothing.

---

### $T_2$

$T_2$ has (1) and (3), which gives us a pre-order. This also makes $f$ more complicated. If $x\neq y$ and $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$, then we can show that $x\leq y$ and $y\leq f(x)$, so $y=f(x)$. Thus also, $x=f(y)$. In particular, our pre-order equivalence classes can't have more than two elements. But (8) says that $f(x)\leq x$ can't happen, so (6) and (8) together prove (1). So $T_2$ contains all the axioms for $T$.

---

### $T_3$

Having a hard time getting my mind around $T_3$. Without (3), you are slightly stuck.